# Creating methods and objects

Tags: java, class, methods

Hello all so I was given this Driver class and was told to make classes to get the driver class working properly. For the most part I think im on the right track but then again im not completely sure because I am new to java. I am getting 2 compiling errors because I have not added a add(temp) method. to be honest im not sure what class to put the method into. for now I have it in the Team class but im getting a compiling error. if anyone can give me some insight it will be well appreciated.

```
public class Driver{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    //All information is stored in input.txt and is being
    //read in below.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    //Creates a new League and passes in a String signifying
    //which league it is.
    League american = new League("AL");
    League national = new League("NL");
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        //Creates a new team and adds the current team
        //to the american league.
        //You can assume there are exactly 15 teams in each league.
        Team temp = new Team(input.next());
        american.add(temp);   // compile error
    }
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        //Creates a new team and adds the current team
        //to the national league.
        //You can assume there are exactly 15 teams in each league.
        Team temp = new Team(input.next());
        national.add(temp);   // compile error 
    }
    }
```

my League class

```
public class League{
private String league;

public League(String League){
     league = League;
}

public void setLeagueAmerican(String League){
    this.league = League;
}

public String getLeagueAmerican(){
    return league;
}

public void setLeagueNational(String national){
    this.league = national;
}

public String getLeagueNational(){
    return league;
}


public void League( String League){

     league = League;

}
}
```

my Team Class

```
public class Team
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String team;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Team
 */
public Team(String Team)
{
    team = Team;
}

public void setTeam(String Team){
    this.team = Team;
}

public String getTeam(){
    return team;
}



public String add(League y)
{

    return y;       //compiling error 
}
}
```

Comment: Always post the compiling errors

Comment: That `add()` method should be in the `League` class: `public void add(Team team) { /* ... */ }`. Also, tag your question with the `java` tag.

Comment: i will add them in just a second

Comment: in the league class was i correct by making a getLeagueAmerican and getLeagueNational and a set for both of them or should i only have a getLeague and setLeague?

Comment: Robbie what would put in the body of the add method?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String add(League y)
{
    return y;       //compiling error 
}
```

This function returns a `String`. You are passing the parameter `y`, which is a `League`. You then try to return the very same `League` as if it was a `String`, which produces the error.

Either change the return type to be a `League`, or don't return `y` but a meaningful String (or even `y.toString()`)